# How to build a complicated Graph without the use of GraphDSL?

Tags: scala, akka-stream

I'd like to build a Flow such as represented in the following asciiFlow :

```
                               Custom Flow

      +-------------------------------------------------------------+
      |                                                             |
      |   +------------------+                                      |
      |   |                  |                                      |
      |   |                  +---------------------------------------------->
      |   |                  |                                      |
+--------->   CustomFanOut2  |       +--------------------+         |
      |   |                  |       |                    |         |
      |   |                  +------->    CustomSink      |         |
      |   +------------------+       |                    |         |
      |                              +--------------------+         |
      |                                                             |
      +-------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Of course, I can use `GraphDSL`, but it boils down to just putting a sink on one of the outlets for `CustomFanOut2`, so it seems that there could be a method

```
Graph[FanOutShape2[I, O0, O1], Mat1].to1(sink: Sink[O1, Any]: Flow[I, O0, Mat1]
```

or equivalents on other inlets and outlets, for other graphs than `Source`, `Flow`, `Sink` and `Bidi`.

Does such a method exist, or could it exist in some future version of akka-stream? In the case where it would not be possible, why is it so?

Comment: What would be the value?

Comment: to avoid the need for the heavy syntax of `GraphDSL` for simple connections. In the example above, it looks a lot like `alsoTo` for `Flow`s  or `Source`, except that the `FanOut` is not necessarily a `Broadcast`. Since one can build a non linear `Flow` with `alsoTo`, it does not seem absurd to think one could also do it with any pair of `Graph`s, assuming the output shape can be deduced from the inputs.

Comment: Your users wouldn't need to use GraphDSL:
def yourThingyMat[I,O0,O1,Mat0, Mat1](sink: Sink[O1, Mat0]): Flow[I, O0, Mat1] = Flow.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create() { implicit builder => …})